# How does an ideal transformer satisfy law of conservation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, energy-conservation, electric-current, voltage

I have read in books and articles that, keeping the power as is transformers increase the voltage and therefore reduce the current
as per the formula 
$$
P = IV
$$
and this results to reduction in heat dissipated due to a resistive load in accordance with the formula 
$$
P = I^2 R
$$
but then again 
$$
V = IR
$$
and 
$$
P=V^2 /R
$$
means that the power delivered should in fact increase if the voltage is increased which is in clear violation of the law of conservation. What am I missing?

Comment: A transformer is not a resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this results to reduction in heat dissipated due to a resistive load

I am not sure if this is just a mistake in wording, or the cause of your confusion, but in a typical power distribution system it is not the load power dissipation which is reduced but the line power dissipation.

The two circuit diagrams below represent possible configurations of a power distribution circuit. The Load resistor represents the power delivered to the customers. The power company has no desire to reduce this because the power consumed by the load is what they are paid for. In order to deliver that power to the customer they must also dissipate some power in the Line. This is a loss that they want to minimize since nobody pays for power lost in the lines.

[image: Power distribution circuits]

Suppose we are looking at a typical 120 MW network. Since the load is operating at 120 V (or something similar depending on location) the current at the load is 1 MA.

Now, if the transformer is a 1000:1 transformer then on the line side we will have 1 kA current and 120 kV voltage across the transformer. This is the load as seen by the generator. The Line is in series with this so it shares the same current, not the same voltage. A typical Line resistance might be 1 Ohm, so that would be 1 MW power dissipated in the Line. That means the generator would have to produce 121 MW to get paid for 120 MW.

Now, suppose instead that the second circuit were used, where the line is directly connected to the load. In that case the same 1 Ohm line resistance would be in series with the 1 MA current. This means that the power dissipated in the line would be 1 TW. That means that the generator would have to produce more than a TW in order to deliver only 120 MW.

Clearly that is not feasible. Resolving this problem is the purpose of the transformer in a power distribution circuit.

Comment: The source needs to show a sinusoidal output, as straight DC current cannot be transformed.

Comment: Yes, good point

Answer (score 1):

For a transformer whose output voltage is double its input voltage, the output current must be half of the input current to satisfy conservation of energy considerations.

Having said that, the transformer itself is electrically resistive, so there is some heat generated as current surges through its primary and secondary coils, and there is also heat generated due to the magnetic hysteresis of its iron (or steel) core.  However, this generated heat and associated $I^2R$ losses are for the *transformer*, NOT for the output voltage and current produced by the transformer.  Using subscripts for the current and resistance of the transformer itself will lead to a proper calculation of power losses for the transformer alone, and separate subscripts for the current and voltage of the secondary coil (i.e., output) of the same transformer, will lead to a proper calculation of the power output of that transformer, which is distinctly different from the $I^2R$ losses of that transformer.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. If you increase the number of windings of the transformer, more current will be drawn from the voltage source. This means the voltage source is outputting more power--energy is still conserved.

Answer (score 0):

Not every $V$ (or $I$ or $R$) is the same.

In $P = V^2/R$, it's telling how much power is dissipated by a resistance, based on the value of the resistance and the voltage drop across that particular resistance.

In most cases, this voltage drop will *not* be equal to the voltage gain by the transformer.